# mysql select from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Maybe this is over-complex, but I can't see to get a result using this query in a WordPress plugin:

I have 4 tables:

- k: child data (id = k.ID)
- p: parent data (id = user_id)
- u: user meta data (id = user_id)
- parent-child relationship data (r.ID | user_id | k.ID)

I'd like to have a result listing all children data with their parent data and the parent names + email (from the meta-data table) based on the relations in the relationship table.

I'm stuck with this:

```
SELECT 
k.*, 
p.*, 
u1.meta_value AS parent_lastname, 
u2.meta_value AS parent_firstname, 
u3.meta_value AS parent_email
FROM kids k, parents p, usermeta u1, usermeta u2, usermeta u3
LEFT JOIN relations r 
  ON (p.user_id = r.user_id 
   AND k.ID = r.kid_id 
   AND u1.user_id = r.user_id 
   AND u2.user_id = r.user_id 
   AND u3.user_id = r.user_id)
WHERE r.user_id = u1.user_id
   AND u1.meta_key = 'last_name'
   OR u2.meta_key = 'first_name'
   OR u3.meta_key = 'email'
GROUP BY k.ID
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing `parent-email` is a typo?

Comment: you shouldn't mixing join syntaxes. use one or the other, not both.

Comment: No. Don't use implicit join syntax. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think the GROUP BY is required. Although if there are 2 parent records for a kid you might want to use that to group the 2 parents to one line - but not sure if that is your requirement. As it is if there were 2 parents for one kid, the parent which would be returned for that kid is undefined.

Assuming all kids will have a parent and all parents will have a first name, last name and email:-

```
SELECT 
k.*, 
p.*, 
u1.meta_value AS parent_lastname, 
u2.meta_value AS parent_firstname, 
u3.meta_value AS parent_email
FROM kids k
INNER JOIN relations r ON k.ID = r.kid_id
INNER JOIN parents p ON p.user_id = r.user_id
INNER JOIN usermeta u1 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'last_name'
INNER JOIN usermeta u2 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name'
INNER JOIN usermeta u3 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'email'
```

If that assumption is wrong then change the INNER JOINs to LEFT OUTER JOINs

```
SELECT 
k.*, 
p.*, 
u1.meta_value AS parent_lastname, 
u2.meta_value AS parent_firstname, 
u3.meta_value AS parent_email
FROM kids k
LEFT OUTER JOIN relations r ON k.ID = r.kid_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN parents p ON p.user_id = r.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta u1 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta u2 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta u3 ON r.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'email'
```

Comment: The GROUP BY may be needed in this case where  one child can have multiple parents - because of your remark I grouped it by relationship ID: if there are multiple parents, the kid shows up more than once.

Correction for the use in WordPress: the user-email is stored in table 'users', not in 'user_meta'. But with this approach a JOIN with the 'users' table can also easily be made.

Comment: If you are happy for a kid to be listed multiple times (once for each parent) then I don't think the GROUP BY is needed. One could be used to group up the parent details into one field if required.